# Is my oven overheating because control components are burned?

Tags: thermostat, oven

My oven suddenly started getting very hot even at low settings. This is a repeat event... 18 months ago it occurred and was fixed with a Controller board replacement. I'm hoping it's the thermostat or something less expensive this time. Stove/Oven is the LG LSB5682SW

I'm wondering if this photo indicates too much heat is leaving the oven and damaging components in the back again.
[image]

Comment: "damaging components in the back again" Is this all _new_ heat damage? i.e. Was it thoroughly cleaned and shiny after the last repair or is some/most/all of this left over from the last overheat issue? If it wasn't cleaned nice and shiny after the last incident, then _you_ are the only one who's going to know if there is additional damage or not (unless you have and share a pic of the previous damage).

Comment: I wish I had a picture from the previous event... if I had to guess, I would guess that some of this damage is "old" and it probably occurred because the oven didn't know to shutoff when it got too hot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terminal in the upper right hand corner appears to have burned and should be checked out and replaced if necessary. That could very well be causing your thermostat to be overridden and cause excessive heat.

Also, something's going on with your blower motor. Check to see if it's burnt or arcing on the other side, the finish looks pitted. Check that the shaft rotates freely and for gaps in any insulation around the shaft.

Comment: Looks like the convection fan motor is burned out.

Comment: I'm thinking there's nothing wrong with that motor, and that the goop from cooking (i.e. smoke) is coming from inside the oven and just finding it's way out through motor/fan hole.

Comment: I'd agree 100% that the connector top right is damaged and should be replaced. However, the OP is asking us if heat is escaping and "damaging components in the back again". _We_ have no way of knowing if that damage is from the current incident or the previous incident. Frankly, there's no way we can answer the only asked question without additional info. (It is common 'round here, though, to point out additional concerns, so I have no issue with this answer as is.)